# What would be the best way to separate items that are in the same column within SQL?

Tags: sql-server

For example I have the below column. The column consists of two types of codes. The codes that include a letter are called HCPC codes and the numeric codes are CPT codes. I need to separate the two types but having trouble finding a way to do so.
Here is the original column:

| Procedure Code |
| --- |
| G2024 |
| 99201 |
| G0348 |
| 99204 |
| 59610 |
| 4665F |

I would essentially need the output to be the following:

| CPT | HCPC |
| --- | --- |
| 99201 | G2024 |
| 99204 | G0348 |
| 59610 | 4665F |

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know that CPT: 99201 pairs with HCPC: G2024? Looking at a reference table? SQL server doesn't guarantee a sort order, unless you specify one. Is procedureCode the only column initially?

Comment: So they don't have to necessarily match with each other. I just have to create two columns from the initial Procedure Code table, one comprising of CPT codes and the other HCPC codes.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have the same number of codes of each type, the below should work if you only care about that one column:

```
SELECT
  c1.ProcedureCode CPT, c2.ProcedureCode HCPC
FROM
  (
    SELECT
          mt.ProcedureCode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) rowNo
    FROM  dbo.myTable AS mt
    WHERE mt.ProcedureCode NOT LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%'
  )   c1
  FULL OUTER JOIN
  (
  SELECT
        mt.ProcedureCode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) rowNo
  FROM  dbo.myTable AS mt
  WHERE mt.ProcedureCode LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%'
  ) c2 ON c2.rowNo=c1.rowNo;
```

If you have other columns in the table that you need to preserve, something more like this:

```
SELECT <other columns>, 
    CASE WHEN ProcedureCode LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%' THEN ProcedureCode END HCPC, 
    CASE WHEN ProcedureCode NOT LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%' THEN ProcedureCode END CPT
FROM dbo.myTable
```

which will preserve other columns, with every row either having a value for HCPC, or a value for CPT, but never both.

Comment: Thank you for the additional code. The query as a whole will include other CTE's and tables so that second one looks like it would be the most viable.
Ran the code and it looks like I will run with this one. Had originally thought of using a case statement but was unaware of '%[A-Za-z]%'

Comment: @agloria, code looks familiar.

Comment: You don't need ELSE part in case.

Comment: Thank you all for the assistance. Looks like some of the CPT codes to have some alphanumeric values, however CPT codes have letters at the end as modifiers (ex. 99207F or 99230TH) and HCPC codes have the letter in the beginning (ex. G2020 or G2024).

Comment: @agloria So I take it that all HCPC codes begin with a letter, and any code which does not begin with a letter is a CPT code? If that's the case, then the pattern `'[A-Za-z]%'` will match HCPC codes but not CPT codes.

Comment: Yes that is correct. But the modification worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said they don't necessarily match with each other and assuming there is even number of rows:

```
SELECT
  c1.ProcedureCode CPT, c2.ProcedureCode HCPC
FROM
  (
    SELECT
          mt.ProcedureCode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) rowNo
    FROM  dbo.myTable AS mt
    WHERE mt.ProcedureCode NOT LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%'
  )   c1
  FULL JOIN
    (
      SELECT
            mt.ProcedureCode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) rowNo
      FROM  dbo.myTable AS mt
      WHERE mt.ProcedureCode LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%'
    ) c2 ON c2.rowNo=c1.rowNo;
```

And here is [DBFiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=05a05397ba225c569c5473ce49b103dc)

Comment: If you make it a full outer join instead of an inner join, it will work even if you don't have the same number of CPT codes as HCPC codes, albeit with some amount of null values in whichever column contains fewer codes.

Comment: Thank you for the code, it ran successfully. However, as Eric mentioned, Cpt codes are more prevalent then HCPC codes. I ran the code with an outer join but got a couple of errors.
1) Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'
2) Incorrect syntax near 'c2'

Comment: the syntax should be correct if you just replace `INNER JOIN` with `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Note that the FULL part is not optional, as with outer joins in SQL server you have to specify which type of outer join (FULL, LEFT, RIGHT) you want.

Comment: @EricMcKeeth, editing for FULL join.

Comment: @agloria, code is correct. Maybe you should share your exact code (you can check in the DbFiddle demo link).